# How to do text writing animation?

Tags: android, animation, textview

I want to create text writing animation like in real life, how to do this on Android? Please help.

[image]

Comment: [Lottie](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android)

Comment: OpenGL ES......

Comment: better create one gif and load it in imageview

Comment: Although I upvoted the **SVG** answer I think the **GIF**comment idea is easier. If it depends on user's specific typing then... Just prepare animations of the "writing" of each letters in A to Z (a.gif, b.gif, c.gif etc) then position each gif (letter) side by side as per user's key press...

Comment: @Nikolay kolomiytsev is the provided solutions are not able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use **SVG** to animate a text or a logo.

see this : [AnimatedSvgView](https://github.com/jaredrummler/AnimatedSvgView)

Answer (score 8):

You can take the animation **After Effects** file from the designer and using Lottie library by Airbnb, you can render it on Android app.

It's an open source library with great features, hope it will solve your problem.

Refer here for Lottie lib:- https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android

It's the best and easy way to perform the variety of animation on Android.

You can also use the solution provided by **@Behnam Eskandari** but the only issue is that it support is only for SVG images.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from @Behnam Eskandari answer, you can also use `Sprite` Animation. It's small and very fast, and doesn't take much space on phone. It's easy to implement too, you just have to make your sprite sheet. You can see the [examples here](https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=example%20sprite%20sheets&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiH9L3K77fVAhULLY8KHZyaCyIQsAQIIg&biw=1366&bih=662).

To achieve this on `Android`, you can use [this library](https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/FPSAnimator). It has some limitations though, but it works fine.

Here is the code how I have used it.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.runningcat);
int width = bitmap.getWidth();
int height = bitmap.getHeight();

int frameWidth = width / 5;    //you have 5 columns
int frameHeight = height / 5;  //and 5 rows
int frameNum = 25;             //there would be 25 images


SpriteSheetDrawer spriteSheetDrawer = new SpriteSheetDrawer(
        bitmap,
        frameWidth,
        frameHeight,
        frameNum)
        .spriteLoop(true)
        .frequency(2);   //change it as per your need


DisplayObject displayObject = new DisplayObject();
displayObject
        .with(spriteSheetDrawer)
        .tween()
        .tweenLoop(true)
        .transform(0, 0) //I have changed it according to my need, you can also do this by changing these values
        .toX(4000, 0)    //this one too.
        .end();
//In actual example, it's set as animation starts from one end of the screen and goes till the other one.


FPSTextureView textureView = (FPSTextureView) findViewById(R.id.fpsAnimation);
textureView.addChild(displayObject).tickStart();
```

Hope it helps.